# Problemas con LDAP_Account_Manager

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

Tengo un problema a la hora de entrar en el servidor de LAM desde el navegador. Lo que ocurre es que al acceder a localhost/lam, no se ejecuta el código PHP de la web, y solo me muestra un montón de código PHP.

He ejecutado el comando `sudo apt-get install ldap-account-manager` y se ha instalado el programa con sus respectivas dependencias (PHP5 y Apache2).

Esto trabajando sobre una máquina virtual de Ubuntu 16.04 LTS de 64bits.

**¿Donde puede encontrarse este error?**

Llevo días dandole vueltas y no encuentro nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Luismi, bienvenido. Deberias sustituir la imagen por el texto del error. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b, buenas. La cosa está en el que no tengo ningún texto de error, debido a que la instalación la realiza correctamente. El problema está al abrir el navegado e introducir la URL localhost/lam, que e carga directamente el contenido que ves en la imagen sin ejecutar el código PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas `php5.6`, solución propuesta:

Añade el `PPA`, ya que por defecto este repositorio no viene en ubuntu 16.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

Instala los siguientes modulos (extensiones):

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-xml

$ sudo apt-get install php5.6-ldap 

$ sudo apt-get install php5.6-zip
```

Reinicia el servicio de Apache:

```
$ service apache2 restart
```

Con esto ya te debería funcionar, a mi me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Me pasa lo mismo que a luismi. Seguí los pasos de la respuesta anterior pero no me funcionó.

Desinstalé LAM, añadí un repositorio y volví a instalar. al seguir estos pasos, funcionó.

Estos son los pasos:

- apt-get remove ldap-account-manager
- editar fichero /etc/apt/sources.list y añadir repositorio -->

  ```
   deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe
  ```
- apt-get update
- apt-get install ldap-account-manager